# Select DataTemplate for ItemsControl depending on ViewModel type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I tried to make my `ItemsControl` display items with different templates depending on its viewModel type. At first look i was think its possible to do like we usually do in `ContentControl`:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModelCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNameSpace:myViewModel1}">
                     <myNameSpace:myControl2/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNameSpace:myViewModel2}">
                     <myNameSpace:myControl2/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

But unfortunately you can not have two `DataTemplate` in `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`.
I found a little trick to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your XAML code just replace the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` tag by `ItemsControl.Resources` and it should work.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModelCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNameSpace:myViewModel1}">
             <myNameSpace:myControl2/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNameSpace:myViewModel2}">
             <myNameSpace:myControl2/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can put `ContentControl` into `ItemsControl` `DataTemplate` and it works.

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModelCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                        <ContentControl.Resources>
                           <ResourceDictionary>
                             <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNameSpace:myViewModel1}">
                                <myNameSpace:myControl2/>
                             </DataTemplate>
                             <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNameSpace:myViewModel2}">
                                <myNameSpace:myControl2/>
                             </DataTemplate>
                          </ResourceDictionary>
                       </ContentControl.Resources>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I'd use `ContentPresenter` rather than `ContentControl`. The latter may bear functional consequences (e.g. both `Focusable` and `IsTabStop` are by default `true` for `ContentControl`, which reflect on keyboard navigation). The former is also more "lightweight".

Comment: Better use none of both. See the other answer.